# What is the minimum Google Kubernetes Engine cluster size / Configuration for Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I tried to launch Istio on Google Kubernetes Engine using the Google Cloud Deployment Manager as described in the Istio [Quick Start Guide](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start-gke-dm/).
My goal is to have a cluster as small as possible for a few very lightweight microservices.

Unfortunately, Istio pods in the cluster failed to boot up correctly when using a 
1 node GKE

- g1-small or
- n1-standard-1

cluster.
For example, istio-pilot fails and the status is "0 of 1 updated replicas available - Unschedulable".

I did not find any hints that the resources of my cluster are exceeded so I am wondering:

**What is the minimum GKE cluster size to successfully run Istio (and a few lightweight microservices)?**

What I found is the issue [Istio#216](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/216) but it did not contain the answer. Also, of course, the cluster size depends on the microservices but I am basically interested in the minimum cluster to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this page](https://istio.io/docs/guides/bookinfo/)

> If you use GKE, please ensure your cluster has at least 4 standard GKE nodes. If you use Minikube, please ensure you have at least 4GB RAM.

Comment: Thanks @jaxxstorm seems I missed this one, I was always searching in the setup guides. But is it in this case only because of the Bookinfo sample or is 4 GKE standard nodes just because of Istio? 4 standard GKE nodes purely for Istio sound pretty heavy.

Comment: It's a little bit of both. If you're planning on running any kind of microserver, the bookinfo is pretty small itself, so it's a reasonable comparison.

Comment: Wow, I thought kubernetes and containers are lightweight (and so is the "transparent" layer Istio). A system with 4 vCPUs and 15GB RAM in total as minimum requirement is heavy for a few lightweight services which can run easily on a single VM with 2 GB RAM (just plain, without Kubernetes). And this also makes a start with Istio very expensive. I might better start off without Istio.